# Undefined index: username when using sessions

Tags: php

I'm working on a forum software right now, and I'm doing very well so far, it all works, but I can't get this to get away, I'm not really sure how.

I get Undefined index: username whenever I call

```
$_SESSION['username']
```

I start the session in a seperate login file, but get this error whenever calling it, I only get it when someone isn't logged in, so like if I'm logged in, it doesn't show it, only when I'm not logged in, how can I get rid of it?

Here's my whole code for the page:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("connect.php");

$find = "SELECT id,name,description FROM forums";  
$run_find = mysql_query("$find");
if ($_SESSION['username']) {
print "Welcome, " . $_SESSION['username']. "!<br/>";
}
while($is = mysql_fetch_assoc ($run_find)) 
{
$id = $is['id'];
$name = $is['name'];
$des = $is['description'];

print "<div style='width:500px;background-color:#FFCCFF;'>";
print "Forum : <a href='topics.php?t=$id'>". $name . "</a><br/>" .$des . "<br/><hr>";
print "</div>";
}

if (!$_SESSION['username']) {
echo "
<form action='loginnext.php' method='post'>
Username: <input type='text' name='username'><br/>
Password: <input type='password' name='password'><br/>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login'><br/></form>";
}
if ($_SESSION['username']) {
echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Which line(s)? Also, you can try `if(isset($_SESSION['username']))`

Comment: Hey thanks, the isset worked.

Answer (score 3):

If the user is not logged in, the session variable will not be set, thus the error message.

Use `if(isset($_SESSION['username']))` instead of `if($_SESSION['username'])`

Answer (score 2):

`if (!empty($_SESSION['username']))` is the construct you wanted. `isset` and `empty` can not throw notices.